# Element wise addition of two unequal lists in python

Tags: python

If `a=[1,2,3,4]` and `b=[1,2,3]`, I want to set `a = a+b`, where the addition happens as long as b extends. After the end of b, the elements are left unaffected. In this case, the result should be `a=[2,4,6,4]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this with some usage of `itertools.izip_longest`.  The `itertools` package is extremely useful for anything dealing with iterable data types.  You could extend this to any number of iterables if you had additional lists you wanted to perform this on.

```
import itertools
map(sum,itertools.izip_longest(a,b,fillvalue = 0))
```

Which gives:

```
[2, 4, 6, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a list comp zipping with [itertools.izip_longest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) using a `fillvalue` of 0 to keep the elements from the longer of the two lists:

```
from itertools import izip_longest # zip_longest python 3

print([i+j for i,j in izip_longest(a,b,fillvalue=0)])
```

If you are doing numerical operations, you may find numpy useful:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
b = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b.resize(a.shape)
print(a+b)
[2 4 6 4]
```